# Selenium ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host error

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web

I am trying to make a program using selenium to refresh the page after it has loaded, and do this indefinitely. (i havent used it before) Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep as s

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe')
while True:
    driver.get('https://advertropolis.g1gabytedev.repl.co/jumbo.php')
    s(3)
    driver.close()
```

And here is the error:
`ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

I tried changing my browser version to the one adjacent to the driver (111) but it still gives me the same error. I need help lol.

Comment: why are you running `driver.close()`?